# Lenovo 3000 N100 7pin miniDIN pinout (TV-out adapter)

Tags: lenovo-laptop, spdif, s-video, composite-video

I have this laptop, and, despite of its being old, I want to know all its capabilities. My question is only regarding 7 pin DIN socket on rear side of the laptop:

[image: This is a part of the Lenovo 3000 N100]

I couldn't find any specification regarding this socket on official Lenovo web pages. But I found an [Intel specification of Intel 965 Express Graphics (p.283)](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/965_g35_vol_3_display_registers_updated_0.pdf) 7pin DIN socket (Lenovo 3000 N100 has 945) and this is what I found:

[image]

I tested it with 7pin DIN to Composite/S-video/Component adaptor and I can confirm that Composite and S-video match the specification. Cannot test Component part though.

According to Intel specification pin 7 is not used. However, Dell Inspiron 1520 according [cnet](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-1520-core-duo-1-66ghz-1-5gb-ram-80gb-hdd-vista-home-basic-series/specs/) has Intel 965 graphics and uses pin 7 for S/PDIF ([according to Dell forums](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Help-with-7-pin-mini-din-pinout-please/td-p/2924201)).

> The question is: what are official Lenovo specification and official accessory regarding this 7pin miniDIN socket? Does it support S/PDIF on pin 7 (I cannot test this at the moment)?